# char conversion

Tags: character-encoding

I want to know what will be the best way for a char-char conversion.

I will create some data for the conversion for example teh letter "A" will be converted to "C" and so on.

Shall I use a MySQL DB or files or what?

Note: The application will be a web app and most likely be running ASP or PHP.

***EDIT:***

I want to create a website or a desktop app that will allow user who work on PCs that only support one language to be able to use any other language something like a translator, yet it is not a translator.

For example, arabic users cannot use the AR keyboard due to system restrictions, I want to help them write in the language without installing the language pack. I`m facing this problem myself, and can`t install language pack without admin access.

I can`t provide output at the moment as the PC I`m using doesn`t support AR.

Comment: Please explain more closely what you want to do (provide an example input and output) and also tell *why* you want to do that.

Comment: @Tomalak: I`ve updaet the question

Comment: I understand what you want to do, but I'm still not sure what your question is exactly.

Comment: Sounds like what you're *really* looking for is an IME written in JavaScript...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess you mean character / keyboard mapping (or an Input Method Editor as Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams said)...

In this case, create static hash maps / associative arrays that map keys to characters or strings.
That said, however, I think there are some keyboard mapping tools out there that hook into the operating system and can be customized to one's needs.

Comment: I need to create it for use at work, and I can`t install any progs (admin issues) ... so I want to create the mapping and teh website.

Comment: I was woundring, how will the mapping process be done? load at runtime in memory? MySQL DB? File and to be loaded?

Comment: You could store a complete mapping for a keyboard in a column of a single record in a database or file as you see fit... encode it in JSON format and then deliver it to your JavaScript - JSON is valid JavaScript and can therefore be embedded directly into the script. Write a keyboard handler that uses the hash map / JS object to map the keys and attach the handler to input elements in HTML.

Comment: I have no idea about the JSON. And I don`t want to use JS as it will be available though the source code.

Comment: The source code will probably be quite simple (less than 50 lines) and therefore there is no big point in trying to protect it from people's eyes. JSON encoding is provided by PHP via `json_encode()` which transforms PHP data to a JSON-format string that you can `echo` into your JS code part.

Comment: And you can still compress JavaScript code e.g. using Yahoo's YUI compressor. It won't be worth the effort to steal trivial code that is compressed. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/compressor/

Answer (score 1):

What about JavaScript?

Here's a simple code for converting the infamous YZ keys to ZY (QWERTY <-> QWERTZ).

```
<textarea id="txt"></textarea>

<script language="JavaScript" type="text/JavaScript">
  document.getElementById("txt").onkeydown = InputKeyDown;
  function InputKeyDown(event) {
    var shift = event.shiftKey;
    var keyCode = (event.which == null) ? event.keyCode : event.which;

    //alert(String.fromCharCode(keyCode) + "\\n" + keyCode); return false;

    switch (keyCode) {
      case 89 /* Y */: InsertAtCursor(event.target, shift ? 'Z' : 'z'); return false;
      case 90 /* Z */: InsertAtCursor(event.target, shift ? 'Y' : 'y'); return false;
      default: return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

I think you could start something with this. You can also use the `event.ctrlKey` or `event.altKey` flags for more complex languages.

Comment: That is great, yet I don`t want to use JS as anyone will be able to copy and alter my codes. I want it to be done in a hidden way. That is why I was aiming for the ASP ... and might go for the Silverlight

Comment: @sikas, I'm not sure how do you want to use ASP for this, you need something client-side. You could send the data to the server and back but that would cause lagging.

Comment: OK, if something is loaded run-time for ASP or Silverlight, I guess that won`t appear to the user on the source code of the page, am I right?

Comment: @sikas, I'm not very familiar with ASP but afaik it only works on the server side. Silverlight would probably work and the user won't see the code. But I don't see the point. As you can see in my code above, the JS script is not that complicated so I wouldn't worry about any code theft. The biggest part of the script is actually putting the mapping pairs together and for anyone trying to get them, they can easily pull that out even from a non-opensource app like Silverlight (simply by posting some string, eg. `qwertyuiop...` and copying the result that comes out).

Comment: It is easier to implement key mapping code by oneself than to try and understand what someone else has written. Copy and paste is not much of an issue as soon as someone wants to customize it to their needs, so they will probably code it themselves anyway.